# How to set Value of JAVA_HOME variable

Tags: java, environment-variables

My /etc/profile code is:

```
# /etc/profile: system-wide .profile file for the Bourne shell (sh(1))
# and Bourne compatible shells (bash(1), ksh(1), ash(1), ...).

if [ "$PS1" ]; then
  if [ "$BASH" ] && [ "$BASH" != "/bin/sh" ]; then
    # The file bash.bashrc already sets the default PS1.
    # PS1='\h:\w\$ '
    if [ -f /etc/bash.bashrc ]; then
      . /etc/bash.bashrc
    fi
  else
    if [ "`id -u`" -eq 0 ]; then
      PS1='# '
    else
      PS1='$ '
    fi
  fi
fi

# The default umask is now handled by pam_umask.
# See pam_umask(8) and /etc/login.defs.

if [ -d /etc/profile.d ]; then
  for i in /etc/profile.d/*.sh; do
    if [ -r $i ]; then
      . $i
    fi
  done
  unset i
fi


JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun
export JAVA_HOME
```

when I am running command echo $JAVA_HOME I am getting:

```
exportib/jvm/java-6-sun
```

I was expecting `/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun`.

Please point how to get the expected value.

Comment: Try putting the value in single quotes, i.e. `JAVA_HOME='/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun'`

Comment: export $JAVA_HOME (should be your last line, with everything else unchanged)

Comment: user133421: Did you log out and back in since making your changes? @mbonaci Environment variables in an `export` command should not be prefixed with `$`. If the variable `FOO` has value `BAR`, `export FOO` exports the `FOO` variable, while `export $FOO` exports the `BAR` variable (i.e., is equivalent to `export BAR`).

Comment: @EliahKagan thanks for clarification.  BTW, AFAIK it's enough to open a new terminal window, no need to log out.

Comment: @mbonaci Commands in "profile" files (e.g., systemwide `/etc/profile`, users' `.profile`s) are specifically run by [login shells](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/38175) (see [`man sh`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/man1/sh.1.html)). In a few configs (not including Ubuntu's default), a profile may be sourced in a file like `.bashrc` that runs for every interactive shell. But generally, environment variables set in `/etc/profile` (or scripts in `/etc/profile.d`, etc.) don't get set in non-login shells that are children of login shells (or desktop sessions) that launched before the change.

Answer (score 2):

Try putting quotes around the location of JAVA_HOME

`JAVA_HOME='/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun'`
`EXPORT JAVA_HOME`

Also you should add system-wide environment variables and exports to a script file in `/etc/profile.d` ex. `/etc/profile.d/java_home.sh` instead of using `/etc/profile`

See:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables

Look under: ***System-wide environment variables***

Comment: I have read the documentation you keep quoting from, and I am telling you: you have misunderstood it. It is not saying that setting environment variables in `/etc/profile` will not work. For many years, `/etc/profile` was the near-universally accepted way to set environment variables for all users, and it is still widespread practice today, and it still works. Editing `/etc/profile`--for *any* reason, this is in no way specific to environment variables--is *not ideal*, even though doing so works. "Not appropriate" does not mean "not effective" or "won't work."

Comment: The reason it's not ideal to edit `/etc/profile` is that if a newer version of the `base-files` package provides a new version of this file, upgrading will usually either (1) discard the changes from the edit, which is bad, or (2) keep the old (changed) file, and not benefit from any of the changes made in the new package's version, which is bad. But editing `/etc/profile` does actually work, and that it works is the reason [the documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables) has to discourage people from doing it. If it didn't work at all, people wouldn't keep doing it.

Comment: Where do you get that info from? That /etc/profile gets discarded from updating base-files package? If you run `apt-file search /etc/profile` there is no match, only matches to `/etc/profile.d/*.sh` script files. I never said adding something to /etc/profile doesn't work... I said it is an `incorrect way` of doing it. I have provided info in my answer, directly quoted from Ubuntu help sources, but you just keep disagreeing with it. I didn't write it, Ubuntu Help did.... https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables

Comment: I am *not* disagreeing with the Ubuntu Help, but we've been through that already. I *didn't* say `/etc/profile` is always discarded when `base-files` is upgraded. Usually the new `profile` doesn't get installed. Upgrading with an interface that allows the user to interact with `dpkg` always gives the user an explicit choice; even then, it's an undesirable situation. (https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ap-pkg-conffiles.html) Files `apt-file` lists are those installed as *package files*, not *configuration files*.

Comment: ...So do you think assigning environment variables in `/etc/profile` works, or not? **If you agree it *does* work, why did you tell the OP that "the result you received is directly related to the use of that file for the wrong reason"?** By the way, would you be interested in [discussing this in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/201/ask-ubuntu-general-room) sometime? Using comments for this is somewhat limiting and difficult. I think chat might work better. You're under no obligation to do this of course; it's just a suggestion.

Comment: I have already said it can work, depending on a lot of other things, so it is considered an incorrect way to do so. It depends on a lot of things... Where in that file you place it. What else (file/package configs) is in the file. Whether you have `/etc/profile.d/*.sh` scripts present (Which is why setting it at the very bottom of `/etc/profile` can still cause errors). And that is just a few things that can cause errors like the one mentioned in Question.

Comment: Setting environment variables in `/etc/profile` is no less likely to work than setting them in a script in `/etc/profile.d`. If you're thinking that perhaps an `/etc/profile.d/*.sh` script could be written extremely poorly and prevent anything in `/etc/profile` after it's sourced from running, you should consider that this would also apply to some of the other `/etc/profile.d/*.sh` scripts. Furthermore, if some `/etc/profile.d/*.sh` script is already setting `JAVA_HOME` (to an undesired value), (re)setting it to the desired value at the end of `/etc/profile` would work *better*.

Comment: NO I don't think that an `/etc/profile.d/*.sh` script is written poorly... I think that the environment variable was **`placed in an incorrect place`**, therefore the system profile for the **Bourne Shell and ALL Bourne Compatible Shells (`bash, sh, ash, & ksh`) `which is what OP would have used to check the result of JAVA_HOME` were not completely and correctly setup yet, so the environment variable was parsed incorrectly! My answer is 2 months old. Only you still dispute that `/etc/profile` is OK for environment variables, when the Ubuntu source says it is incorrect!**

Answer (score -1):

should be:

```
 export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun
```

Comment: While stylistically I agree, this has the same effect as the line `JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun` followed immediately by the line `export JAVA_HOME` (which is what the OP says does not work).